# Istio Authorization with JWT

Tags: authorization, jwt, rbac, istio

I am running isio 1.0.2 and am unable to configure service authorization based on JWT claims against Azure AD.

I have succesfully configured and validated Azure AD oidc jwt end user authentication and it works fine.

Now I'd like to configure RBAC Authorization using request.auth.claims["preferred_username"] attribute.
I've created a ServiceRoleBinding like below:

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRole
metadata:
  name: service-reader
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - services: ["myservice.default.svc.cluster.local"]
    methods: ["GET"]
    paths: ["*/products"]
---
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: service-reader-binding
  namespace: default
spec:
  subjects:
  - properties:
      source.principal: "*"
      request.auth.claims["preferred_username"]: "user@company.com"
  roleRef:
    kind: ServiceRole
    name: "service-reader"
```

However, I keep getting 403 Forbidden from the service proxy, even though preferred_username claim from Authentication header is correct.
If I comment out `request.auth.claims["preferred_username"]: "user@company.com"` line the request succeeds.

Can anyone point me in the right direction regarding configuring authorization based on oidc and jwt?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the problem.
I was missing user: "*" check to allow all users.
so under subjects it should say:

```
subjects:
  - user: "*"
    properties:
      source.principal: "*"
      request.auth.claims["preferred_username"]: "user@company.com"
```

That fixes it.